# Swift - Inherited Protocol Associated Type Erasure

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I've got 3 protocols and a function which has to determine the most specialized protocol

```
protocol Super {}
protocol Sub1: Super { associatedtype T }
protocol Sub2: Super {}

func test(_ s: Super) { ... do stuff }
```

Now I've tried it with type erasure

```
class AnySub<E>: Sub1 {
    typealias T = E
    // ... standard type erasure init
}
```

with following changes:

```
protocol Super {
    func tryAsSub1() -> AnySub? {}
}
extension Sub1 { 
    func tryAsSub1() -> AnySub<T> { return AnySub<T>() }
}
extension Sub2 {
    func tryAsSub1() -> AnySub { return nil }
}
func test(_ s: Super) {
    if let sub1 = s.tryAsSub1() { ... do stuff for Sub1 }
    else let sub2 = s as? Sub2 { ... do stuff for Sub2 }
}
```

But that obviously does not work, because I don't have any generic parameter in Super and Sub2.
Does anybody have an idea, how I can solve this?

Comment: I don't see a protocol hierarchy in your code.

Comment: Forgot the hierarchy when tiping. Nevertheless this is just pseudo code

Comment: Why do you need the type eraser? I don't see it used in your code excepting the protocol extensions

Comment: It is supposed to be used in the edited test function (forgot it there too). As I said, function test needs to determine the specialised type of a value. Since Sub1 has an associated type, I cannot use "as? Sub1" or the is operator. Now I've tried to erase the type to be able to cast it. If there's a way to achieve this besides type erasure, I am open to new things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Sub1` uses associated types, you cannot determine at runtime if a certain variable is of that type. Type erasers help to a certain degree, however it's hard to use multiple eraser types. My recommendation would be to overload the `test` method for every type you need to handle. This also adds more type safety to you code.

```
func test<S: Sub1, T>(_ s: S) where S.T == T

func test(_ s: Sub2)
```

The above solution won't work however for the scenario where you have a collection of `Super` elements, and you need to execute some actions based on the actual type. For this scenario a possible approach is to move the `test` method at the protocol level, and override in the child protocols.

```
protocol Super {
    func test()
}

protocol Sub1: Super { associatedtype T }

protocol Sub2: Super {}

extension Sub1 {
    func test() { ... do stuff for Sub1 }
}

extension Sub2 {
    func test() { ... do stuff for Sub2 }
}
```

The downside is that conformers can override `test`, thus you'd loose the original implementation.